# Jquery Append html

Tags: jquery, slider, append

I am having trouble appending a link, retrieved dynamically and used on a slideshow/featured post.

These 2 functions work, and append my H1 and P tag correctly with values retrieved from my PHP loop

```
function onBefore() { 
    $('#slidertext').html('<h1></h1>','<p></p>');
    if (window.console)
        console.log(this.id); 
} 
function onAfter() { 
    $('#slidertext').append('<h1>' + this.title + '</h1>');
    $('#slidertext').append('<p>' + this.alt + '</p>');
}
```

How can I do the same with a HREF link? If I try

```
$('#slidertext').append('<a href=' + this.link + '></a>');
```

I get value undefined...

Comment: have you checked the value of your `this.link` ? maybe that is the culprit? try `alert(this.link)` to see its contents

Answer (score 0):

If it is an anchor, you can use the `href` property.